# How to use overwrite function on GRASS GIS?

Tags: r, qgis, grass

I was trying to replicate this exercise of mikerspencer
https://www.r-bloggers.com/spatial-networks-case-study-st-james-centre-edinburgh-13/

I add the data to qgis and then i opened the grass tools to do the first step:

```
# connect postcodes to streets as layer 2
v.net --overwrite input=roads points=postcodes output=roads_net1 operation=connect thresh=400 arc_layer=1 node_layer=2
```

although, i can't find the overwrite option.

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.
Raquel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aim to overwrite the existing file simply add `--overwrite` to you line of code.

In you case it is alread the 1st command `v.net` **--overwrite** `input=roads points=postcodes output=roads_net1 operation=connect thresh=400 arc_layer=1 node_layer=2`